# Selecting lines between co-ordinates

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas

This is more a request for advice rather than help with broken code, but please bear with me...

I've designed the image at the below link using a fairly primitive HTML5 canvas. It draws the individual passes a player makes during a football match, as well as the pitch itself. This works perfectly fine.

[image]
http://tinypic.com/r/zj6ydk/5

At first, this was all I was hoping to do, however, I now want to expand this so that I can click each line, and it will load up specific information outside of the element via AJAX about that pass (who passed it etc). I'm thinking that jQuery can help me out here, but to be honest, I don't know? I've done a lot of googling, but I suspect I'm searching for the wrong thing.

Does anybody know if there is a jQuery script that will allow me to do something like this? I'm not asking for you to write any code for me, I'd prefer to learn what I'm doing. I just need pointing in the right direction.

Cheers

Comment: jquery won't help, but check out one of these libraries that turn lines into objects that can respond to mouse clicks: FabricJS, KinetcJS, EaselJS, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am conflicted…**

On the one hand, I agree with @Ken - Abdias Software that the best way to learn about programming is to take an example that interests you and start coding from scratch.  The PRO of coding from scratch is harnessing the amazing flexibility of html canvas.  The CON is the steep learning curve.

On the other hand, one might desire to create an app about something that interests you—and secondarily gain a little programming knowledge in the process.  In this case, leveraging a canvas library seems appropriate.    The PRO of using a library is ease of getting started.  The CON is you are often limited by the abilities of the library.

Since Ken has given a code-from-scratch example, I’ll reluctantly give an example from the other side of my conflicted feelings!

This KineticJS canvas library code example will do the following things in about 20 lines of code:

- Easily create as many passing lines as you need from point-A to pointB.
- Highlight any line by changing color when you hover over that line.
- Call an external function (could be an AJAX call) when any line’s head is doubleclicked.
- Handle all the hit-testing for you, even when the line is rotated.
- The library allows multiple layers, so the futbol field is easily shown under the lines.

Here’s an example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/4gcDy/

And here’s a  20 line function that creates the useful lines:

```
// create a new line
function newLine(x1,y1,x2,y2,id){
    var dx=x2-x1;
    var dy=y2-y1;
    var L=Math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy);
    var r=Math.atan2(dy,dx);
    var line = new Kinetic.Polygon({
      id:id, x:x1, y:y1,
      points: [0,0,L-10,0,L-10,-5,L,0,L-10,5,L-10,0],
      stroke: 'blue', strokeWidth: 2, fill:"blue",
      rotation:r,
    });
    line.recolor=function(color){
        this.setStroke(color);
        this.setFill(color);
        layer.draw();
    }
    line.on("click",function(){ajaxCall(this.getId());});
    line.on("mouseover",function(){this.recolor("orange");});
    line.on("mouseleave",function(){this.recolor("blue");});
    layer.add(line);
    layer.draw();
}
```

My personal choice would be to code-from-scratch and learn-like-crazy!  But that's me...

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful reply. I had already begun to look at the various libraries you had suggested previously, and recognised that KineticJS was probably going to be the most useful for my needs.

You've given me a great foundation here to build upon, and hopefully I can integrate this in to my project, as well as using it to get a better understanding of client-side languages :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn it from bottom up I would recommend anyone to avoid any library.

You can create an internal object for each line that keeps all vital information such as the line coordinates, source and any other type of information you want to attach.

Then look at the canvas as a simple passive view-port/render of the lines from those objects.

**Example:**

```
function myObject() {
    this.line = [x1, y1, x2, y2]; /// initialize with constructor of manually
    this.source = 'Bob';
    ... any other information ...
    return this;
}
```

Now you have an object. You can simply store these into an array:

```
var objectStack = [];

var object1 = new myObject();
object1.line = [0, 0, 100, 100];
object1.source = 'Joe';
...

objectStack.push(object1);

/// next
```

The next logical step will of course be to render the objects to canvas. As canvas is only a pixel pool and doesn't work with objects it will only function as a viewport for these data.

However, since you internally work with objects you can grab the coordinate from canvas and use that to check each object. You *can* use jQuery at this stage if you want to but it is really not necessary:

```
canvas.onclick = function(e) {

    /// adjust coordinates   
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),
        x = e.clientX - rect.left,
        y = e.clientY - rect.top;

    /// iterate objects
    ...   
}
```

For simple lines you can either use the `isPointInStroke()` (you can see for example [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935737/text-collision-detection/18935984#18935984) on how to use it) function of context or you can use other mathematical approaches to determine if the point is on the line.

If it is current object will be the object you need.

Another advantage with this approach is that you can incorporate methods and functions that self-update the object to canvas and so forth.

If you *don't* want to do this manually you can always use one of the many libraries out there that do all this for you but will limit you to how they define the objects.