# Hit testing against text shapes

Tags: html5-canvas, raphael, paperjs

I want to know whether a given point is inside or outside of a text shape. As you will notice in the sample I provided below, `hitTest` will return `true` as soon as the point is inside of the `TextItem`'s bounds, and not only if the point is inside of the character itself. (You can experience this behavior best when you place your mouse pointer in the middle of the `#`)

[Sample: Hit-testing against TextItem](http://jsfiddle.net/rponudic/pf323b2r/)

I also tried drawing the character based on paths (as `Raphaël` is doing in their [font samples](http://raphaeljs.com/fonts.html)) to use the paths itself for hit-testing but stumbled upon some quite strange behavior where (some) characters are not drawn correctly. (If you copy the path definition into a vector image software like `Inkscape` the text shapes are drawn correctly)

[Sample: Drawing text as path](http://jsfiddle.net/rponudic/zdyLeqvm/)

What is the most promising way to find out whether a given point is inside or outside of a text shape?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe the path shows up wrong as I don't think canvas supports fillRule properly yet, which is in SVG. I may be wrong though. Do you need to use Canvas ? Sounds like SVG may be more suited (or both) ?

Comment: I've also done an example with *exact* the same cufon font in `Raphaël` and the font rendered as expected. Generally I'm open to use other methods, unfortunatelly the result of hit-testing with svg is exactly the same: http://jsfiddle.net/rponudic/6st4Lodc/

Comment: Hit-testing against paths works in SVGs: http://jsfiddle.net/rponudic/fa8v2k6u/ - this would be a possible solution, although this is quite a workaround...

Comment: Basically I was wondering if you could just overlay the Canvas with SVG for the text on top for the bits where you need fine control of paths.

Comment: Missed the earlier comment. In Raph/svg, not sure why you are adding a box and putting the mousemove on that. Why not just have mousemove on the path only ?

Comment: Maybe this can be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935737/text-collision-detection/18935984#18935984

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quite some time debugging `paper.js` code I finally found the solution for this problem.

Instead of using `Path` you are supposed to use `CompoundPath`:

> A compound path contains two or more paths, holes are drawn where the paths overlap. All the paths in a compound path take on the style of the backmost path and can be accessed through its item.children list.

I also updated the example from above:

http://jsfiddle.net/64v7s6L9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can hit-test a text shape (or any other mathematically irregular shape) by texting whether the pixel under the mouse is transparent or not.

You can get the pixel-array for the entire canvas using:

```
var data=context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;
```

Then you can fetch the opacity (alpha) value for the pixel under the mouse like this:

```
var pixelIsTransparent = data[(mouseY*canvas.width+mouseX)*4+3]==0
```

If the pixel is not transparent then you're over the text shape.

If you have other non-text drawings on the canvas then those non-text drawings might give false-positives for your hit-tests.  A workaround for that is to use a second in-memory canvas containing only your text-shape and then do hit testing against the pixels on that second canvas.

Here's example code and a Demo:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;
var $canvas=$("#canvas");
var canvasOffset=$canvas.offset();
var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;

ctx.strokeStyle='gray';
ctx.font='300px verdana';
var wasHit=false;
var isHit=false;

draw();

var data=ctx.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height).data;

$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});


function draw(){
  ctx.fillStyle=(isHit)?'green':'lightgray';
  ctx.fillText("M",25,250);
  ctx.strokeText("M",25,250);
}


function handleMouseMove(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();

  mouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
  mouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);

  isHit=(data[(mouseY*cw+mouseX)*4+3]>10)
  if(!isHit==wasHit){
    draw();
    wasHit=isHit;
  }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Hit test: Move mouse over letter</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```