# How to detect user has drawn a certain path using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I want to create a small activity where user will be required to draw certain predefined shape using Javascript/Jquery.

But I am not able to figure out a way to validate what the user has drawn.

I will appreciate any help as to how to approach this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's a possible starting point...You can hit-test if the mouse clicks (or drag-draws) are inside a predefined shape like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375877/hit-testing-against-text-shapes/26387527#26387527.  You can estimate how much of the shape has been clicked/drawn by using destination-out compositing to clear pixels within a radius of each click/dragpoint. Then compare the resulting pixel count with the original fully-pixeled shape and determine if they have cleared enough pixels to declare the shape officially "drawn".

Comment: Another way is to draw waypoints along the path of the shape. Then hit-test of the user is clicking/dragging along each sequential waypoint. You can hit-test by comparing the mouse position with a radius around each sequential waypoint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of the following jQuery commands: for .mousedown(), .mouseenter(), .mousemove(), .mouseup(), .mouseleave(), .mouseenter()? I assume that you will be monitoring the user's mouse movement especially the interaction between the mouse and a predefined space in the browser. Depending on that, you can place a listener that monitors their mouse movement from the user.

Hope this helps.

Thomas